# Как можно увеличить расстояние между графиками(subplot) в Python?

Tags: python, графики

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать расстояние между графиками больше, чтобы текст на осях Y правых графиков не залезал на левые графики?

```
plt.subplot(2,2,1)  
plt.plot(tn,y1n,'r-*') 
plt.axis([0,Tnab,-1.1*A,1.1*A])  
plt.title('Дискретизация по Найквисту')  
plt.xlabel('Time, sec')  
plt.ylabel('Сигнал')

plt.subplot(2,2,2)  
plt.plot(tv,y1v,'g') 
plt.axis([0,Tnab,-1.1*A,1.1*A])  
plt.title('Дискретизация в '+ str(mvis) + ' раз точнее')  
plt.xlabel('Time, sec') 
plt.ylabel('Сигнал')

plt.subplot(2,2,3) 
plt.plot(tn,y2n,'r-*') 
plt.axis([0,Tnab,-1.1*A,1.1*A]) 
plt.xlabel('Time, sec') 
plt.ylabel('Сигнал')

plt.subplot(2,2,4) 
plt.plot(tv,y2v,'g') 
plt.axis([0,Tnab,-1.1*A,1.1*A]) 
plt.xlabel('Time, sec') 
plt.ylabel('Сигнал')
```

Answer (score 4):

Регулировка расстояний между субграфиками выполняется по обоим осям с помощью

```
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=, hspace=)
```

Поскольку вы не привели минимально воспроизводимый код, на котором можно было бы что-то поэкспериментировать - подбирайте вариант, который вас устроит самостоятельно. У меня сработало (0.3,0.3)

Comment: Спасибо большое! Помогло.

Comment: @Nast  -  как новичку на этом сайте, подсказываю: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Можно еще дополнительно в название таблицы символ конца строки поместить, чтобы название таблицы на двух строках помещалось, будет лучше смотреться. А может и изменять расстояние тогда не понадобится.
plt.title('Дискретизация \n по Найквисту')